# PHP regular expression syntax for word phrase?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am new to PHP regular expression syntax. Using the following two lines, I was able to phrase a website depending on the following characters  `:`  `’`  `newline`  `”`

```
$html = @file_get_contents("http://news.yahoo.com");
$webwords = preg_split("/[:'\n\"]+/", $html);
```

Above code will only allow me to phrase a website depending on individual characters. Can you please tell me how I can parse a website with `word phrases` ? For example, above individual characters alone with the word `image_17`

```
$webwords = preg_split("/[:'\n\"]+ | (image_17) /", $html);     ??
```

Comment: Don't use spaces in your expression or use `/x` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe do you need something similar?

```
$html = 'xxx:yyyimage_17aaa:9999';
$webwords = preg_split("/([:'\n\"]+|image_17)/", $html);
print_r($webwords);
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xxx
    [1] => yyy
    [2] => aaa
    [3] => 9999
)
```